# php undefined variable / not detecting class

Tags: php, html, pdo

i'm working for some fun projects but i'm stuck at the moment. every time i call my index.php i get a notice and a fatal error.

`Notice: Undefined variable: translator in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curve\manage\pages\menu.sfwp on line 309`

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getText() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curve\manage\pages\menu.sfwp on line 309`

i required all files and called my class.

structure:
index.php -> core/core.inc.php -> classes/Translator.cs.php
index.php -> pages/menu.sfwp

core:

```
if(corekey != "STR456512013213280935405CMS"){
    die();
}
//Sessionn
session_start();

//MySQL Connection
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Curve", 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $Exception){
    throw new Exception( $Exception->getMessage( ) , $Exception->getCode( ) );
}

//classes
require('classes/General.cs.php');
require('classes/Users.cs.php');
require('classes/Portal.cs.php');
require('classes/Translation.cs.php');

$users          = new users($conn);
$general        = new general($conn);
$portal         = new portal($conn);
$templatePortal = new portalTemplate($conn);
$translator     = new Translator($conn);
```

Menu.sfwp

```
<?php $translator->getTxt(1, $_SESSION['lang']); ?>
```

translator.cs.php

```
class Translator
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    }

    private function getTxt($text, $userlang){
        $lang = "lang_".$userlang;
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$lang." WHERE id='".$text."'");
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetch();
        echo($row->text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard the word 'debug'? If yes, did you tried it?

Comment: How is `Menu.sfwp` connected to core? Also, `getTxt` is a private method. It needs to be public to be accessable outside the class itself.

Comment: make sure your `menu.sfwp` file contains instance of translator..

Comment: @OptimusCrime He's calling `getText` so it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Isn't the function name `getTxt`?

Comment: @ElonThan Oh, well. Yet another mistake. Problem is that I don't really see how these files are connected. The file structure makes no sense to me. Looks like the file is not included correctly in menu.sfwp.

Comment: it isn't the spelling also translator is defined in my core and is required into my index same as menu.sfwp so should work like all the other classes i've got

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_once('classes/Translation.cs.php');` in Menu.sfwp

```
<?php 
$translator=new Translator($conn);

$translator->getText(1, $_SESSION['lang']); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Menu.sfwp` you're trying to call `getText` method which doesn't exist.
Your `Translator` class has `getTxt` method instead.
**It's a typo.**

Your `Menu.wfwp` should look like this:

```
<?php $translator->getTxt(1, $_SESSION['lang']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Menu.sfwp should have

```
<?php 
   $translator     = new Translator($conn);
   $translator->getText(1, $_SESSION['lang']);
?>
```

Also check the spelling of getTxt.

Comment: it isn't the spelling also translator is defined in my core and is required into my index same as menu.sfwp